# Spring Data Repository ignores Hibernate's @Convert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following native query:

```
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
        "INSERT INTO my_entity (update_date_time) " +
        "VALUES (:#{#e.getUpdateDateTime()}) " +
        "ON CONFLICT (hash) DO NOTHING RETURNING *")
Long insert(MyEnitity e);
```

Here is mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;    
    @Column(name = "update_date_time")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;
....
}
```

It works if I call Repository.save(MyEntity). But by some reason when call this query spring data ignores @Convert annotation and do not call converter for field *updateDateTime* although it uses hibernate query under the hood.  I guess it because of it's native query and hibernate knows only about db columns and not about entity fields. Any ideas how tell spring and hibernate use my converter when executing native query.

Comment: Ofcourse it will ignore it. You are executing a native SQL query which completely bypasses the JPA type system.

Comment: I see, any workaround to manage with this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I applied the following workaround. I've added required for me function to spring evaluation context like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {

    private static final Map<String, Function> functions = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        functions.put("ldt2timestamp", createLdt2timestampFunc());
    }

    private static Function createLdt2timestampFunc() {
        Method convertToDatabaseColumn =
                ReflectionUtils.findMethod(LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class,
                        "convertToDatabaseColumn", LocalDateTime.class);

        return new Function(convertToDatabaseColumn,
                LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Function> getFunctions() {
        return functions;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "custom";
    }

}
```

After I call *ldt2timestamp* in the following way in my queries:

```
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
        "INSERT INTO my_entity (update_date_time) " +
        "VALUES (:#{#root.ldt2timestamp(#e.getUpdateDateTime())}) " +
        "ON CONFLICT (hash) DO NOTHING RETURNING *")
Long insert(MyEntity e);
```

It works for me. Hope this will help someone.